# Rounded bolt head on possibly broken bolt

Tags: tools, scooter

I'm trying to remove the transmission casing on my belt drive scooter. All of the bolts have tiny 8mm heads, and are very cheap and soft - cheap Chinese manufacture - and one was already slightly rounded, from assembly as a new bike.

I have now sprayed Q10 penetrating oil, and waited a few minutes before tapping lightly with a hammer, on the front and sides of the bolt head. What is really worrying is that when I tap the side of the bolt head, it moves as much as 0.7mm, in any direction. The head is too close to a casing piece to get any good grip with a vice grip.

What can I do here? There is no room to cut a groove with a hacksaw, but maybe if I get a thin enough grinding disk on an angle grinder I can cut a groove, or maybe grind the head flat enough for a vice grip to hold.

What can I do?

Comment: A picture might help us make a more specific recommendation.

Comment: Do you have a Dremel that you could slot it with? (Or a friend with a Dremel?)

Comment: I found a miniscule angle to get a hacksaw in and cut a slot in the bolt head. Then I hammered a screwdriver into that and shocked it left and right with locking pliers.

Answer (score 4):

You can try heating it with a torch to loosen it.  You could also get a reverse-direction drill bit, and drill down into the bolt; the heat will help the reverse bit to unscrew it, and if not then you can easily get the remainder of the bolt out by stepping up bit sizes.

Comment: The reverse direction drill bit might be perfect for this application.